# Explain request.setURI

Tags: java, android, http-get

I am beginner to Android:
I have a QueryString = `"http://www.google.com/Test/?Param1=ABC&Param2=DEF";`

I want to send this QueryString to Server (Make a Server Request. To pass Variables to asp.net page and store parameters to Database).

So I am sending this to server using GET. And doing this in `AsyncTask<String, Void, Long>`

I found this code on StackOverflow. (I have made some modifications to this code)

```
protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {
        Long result = null;
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {        
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setURI(new URI(params[0]));
                response = client.execute(request);
                result = 1L;
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            return result;
        }
```

Please explain these 2 lines of code:

```
request.setURI(new URI(params[0]));
response = client.execute(request);
```

What value is in params[0] and

will  `response = client.execute(request);` send the variable to my asp.net page?

**An Edit - Another Question -** 
If i send more than one string to the AsyncTask

then to each HTTP-GET Request I can do this with 'i' increasing on a loop?

```
request.setURI(new URI(params[i]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about AsyncTask before you used: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
 params is an array that you pase to the AsyncTask: 
 doInBackground(String... params)// String... params = String [] params

 response = client.execute(request);// yes it will... This line send your request to your service (php, c#, etc, etc)... and on your service you should handle the params your are passing
```

Comment: Please see my edit I have made. Please let me know how to send multiple HTTP-GET Requests when sending more than one String Parameter

Comment: sure you can do that but keep in mind that DOCS: AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)

Comment: So you suggest I use something else to send HTTP-GET request?

Comment: no,  depends of your needs, also I am referring to the use of asynctask

Answer (score 1):

When the last value in Java is passed as (String x...) it is the same as saying (String[] x), passing in an array.

The calling procedure is a little different though, when you are calling  you may either pass a string array or you may pass a list of strings that will be made into a string array.

For example, you could call the above like this:

doInBackground("a","b","c"), and you would get an aray params[] with 3 elements.

Your question--params[0] would be "a"

Answer (score 1):

> request.setURI(new URI(params[0]));

params is the array that you get containing all of the values passed to the variable length parameter of doInBackGround(). You retrieve the desired parameter using the index that corresponds to the order the parameter was passed.

> response = client.execute(request);

It will perform the constructed request, and interact with the server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Where you are creating and calling the asynctask to execute you give a parameter(QueryString) to the:

`protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {`

the (String... params) means that the function can have zero or more string values so whenever you give a string to the doInBackground it receives a Array of strings (in this case your QueryString). To get the Querystring you can use **params[0]**.

```
response = client.execute(request);
```

this executes the request created and gets the response in the response object.